# wxpython: Prevent horizontal growth of specific fields

Tags: wxpython

I have a gui with 3 basic areas.  A list control that spans the entire width of the window above two areas of buttons that are grouped based on function of the button.

When the window is resized all 3 areas are resized in proportion to the growth of the window.  What I want to happen is the two button areas to not do any height growth, but would allow width growth.

Is this possible?

Here is what I am using as an example.  I generated this using wxGlade

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.3 on Thu Apr 14 07:05:59 2011

import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade



class mainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: mainFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.panelLower = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.panelUpper = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.sizerPassword_staticbox = wx.StaticBox(self.panelLower, -1, "Password Settings")
        self.sizerInstall_staticbox = wx.StaticBox(self.panelLower, -1, "Install Actions")
        self.sizerStatus_staticbox = wx.StaticBox(self.panelUpper, -1, "Status")
        self.listStatus = wx.ListCtrl(self.panelUpper, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.list_ctrl_1 = wx.ListCtrl(self.panelLower, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: mainFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_1")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: mainFrame.__do_layout
        mainSizer = wx.GridSizer(2, 1, 0, 0)
        sizerLower = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)
        sizerInstall = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizerInstall_staticbox, wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizerInstallButtons = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)
        sizer_4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizerPassword = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizerPassword_staticbox, wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizerPasswordButtons = wx.GridSizer(3, 8, 0, 0)
        sizerStatus = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizerStatus_staticbox, wx.VERTICAL)
        sizerStatus.Add(self.listStatus, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.panelUpper.SetSizer(sizerStatus)
        mainSizer.Add(self.panelUpper, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizerPassword.Add(sizerPasswordButtons, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizerLower.Add(sizerPassword, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizerInstallButtons.Add(self.list_ctrl_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizerInstallButtons.Add(sizer_4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizerInstall.Add(sizerInstallButtons, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizerLower.Add(sizerInstall, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.panelLower.SetSizer(sizerLower)
        mainSizer.Add(self.panelLower, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

# end of class mainFrame


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    mainFrame = mainFrame(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(mainFrame)
    mainFrame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
        self.panel3 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        self.sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer1.Add(self.panel1, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer1.Add(self.panel2, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.panel3, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.sizer1, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer2)       
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Also not quite.  You have 3 stacked panels.  I need one panel above 2 side by side.

Comment: This works, but now I have to figure out how to apply it to my example.  Thanks for the assist

Comment: @ccwhite1 - You can also use Grid sizers, they are a bit easier to understand in my opinion. There are excellent examples in wxPython demos.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
import wx


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, None)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        bSizer1.Add(panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        panel2 = wx.Panel(self, size=(-1, 50))
        bSizer2.Add(panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        panel3 = wx.Panel(self, size=(-1, 50))
        bSizer2.Add(panel3, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer1.Add(bSizer2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.TopWindow = f = Frame()
f.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not quite.  I only get a single frame w/ a green background on that example.

Comment: Just to make sure, I tried my example on three different wxPython versions (2.6, 2.8 and 2.9) on windows and linux. Every time I got the correct output (like the screenshot). Maybe you somehow get the bottom two panels to have a hight of 0, though I'm not sure why. Anyway the panels are not important, try out this sizer layout with your controls.

Comment: It did not work on my system either. OS: Windows XP SP3, Python: 2.7.1, wxPython: 2.8.11.0.

Comment: Im also at 2.7 on XP sp3.  Is it the wx.HORIZONTAL that defines the direction it expands?

Comment: @ccwhite1 For the wx.BoxSizer wx.HORIZONTAL determines how the sizer items are stacked in the sizer, wx.EXPAND makes an item expand (in every direction), and the proportion parameter determines the expansion along the staking direction relative to other sizer items (0 for no expansion). The proportion parameter is key for what you want to do. Try fiddling with a gui designer like wxFormBuilder to better understand these things visually.